# Use Laplace transformations to solve $y''+4y'+4y=e^{-x}$, so that $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Use Laplace transformations to solve $y''+4y'+4y=e^{-x}$, so that $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=1$.

I applied the transformation but I don't understand the rest of the process. Can anyone explain me based on this exercise?

Thanks

Comment: What have you got so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laplace transforms are great because they are just algebra intensive. The process begins by  transforming your equation. $$\mathcal{L}\{y''+4y'+4y=e^{-x} \}\\ \implies s^2Y(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)+4(sY(s)-y(0))+4Y(s) = \frac{1}{s+1}$$ Now plug in $y(0)= 0, \space y'(0)=1$ to get $$s^2Y(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)+4(sY(s)-y(0))+4Y(s)=s^2Y(s)-1+4sY(s)+4Y(s)$$ Factor out $Y(s)$ on the RHS of the equation above to get $$Y(s)(s^2+4s+4)-1=\frac{1}{1+s} \\ \implies Y(s)(s^2+4s+4) = \frac{s+2}{s+1} \\ \implies Y(s) = \frac{s+2}{(s+1)(s^2+4s+4)}$$ Now simply apply an inverse transform to both sides and you'll get back $y(x)$. The quantity $ \frac{s+2}{(s+1)(s^2+4s+4)}$ may look challenging to inverse transform. Remember that algebra is your friend in Laplace transforms, and observing that $(s^2+4s+4)$ can easily be factored into a square will make things a lot easier. Lastly, you should be able to use partial fraction decomposition, at which point you'll be left with an expression that should be very easy to inverse transform.

Answer (score 4):

The process is:

- Apply Laplace transform, this yields an equation that has some terms with $\mathscr L\{y(x)\}(s)$.
- Solve for $\mathscr L\{y(x)\}(s)$, which is normally denoted by $Y(s)$.
- Once you solved the equation, apply the inverse of laplace transform and you will get $y(x)$.

Example:

$$y'+4y=1,~~~~~~~~~~~ y(0)=1.$$

If we apply Laplace transform:

$$sY(s)-y(0)+4Y(s)=\frac{1}{s},$$
$$Y(s)(s+4)=\frac{1}{s}+1.$$
Now we solve for $Y(s)$:
$$Y(s)=\frac{1}{s(s+4)}+\frac{1}{s+4}\stackrel{\text{Use partial fractions.}}{=}\frac{1}{4s}+\frac{3}{4(s+4)}.$$
Finally we apply inverse Laplace transform:
$$y(x)=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4}e^{-4x}.$$